# Best way to update table attribute with calculated value from another table JDeveloper

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdeveloper

I have a simple ER diagram. Payment : Payment_Product = Master : Detail.

So first I have to insert into Payment and then into Payment_Product. TotalSum default is null. After Commit I want TotalSum to be calculated based on Product.Price and Payment_Product.Quantity.

What is the best way to do this in JDeveloper (12.1)?

[Payment Product ER Diagram Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM0YO.jpg)

Comment: Are you looking for Java code to do this? Or for a SQL statement? Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am looking for Java code. DBMS = SQL Developer

Comment: Why not use a trigger (in DB)?

Comment: SQL Developer is not a DBMS, it's a SQL Client